# any python tools to build a complex url with get parameters?

Tags: python, http, rest, url, get

I wonder if there is some library that allows me to build complex urls with a lot of parameters. Something like the following:

```
request = {
  'protocol': "http",
  'hostname': "www.example.com",
  'port': "80",
  'page': "/foo/bar/example.php",
  'parameters': {
    'foo': "spaced parameter",
    'quuz': 42
  }
}

url = urlbuilder.build(request)
```

At this point the variable `url` will contain the following string:

```
http://www.example.com:80/foo/bar/example.php?foo=spaced%20parameter&quuz=42
```

any ideas?

Comment: `urlparse` in the std lib.

Comment: Do you specifically want to have the built URL, or do you want to send a request with those parameters?

Comment: @user2357112: I just need my url built, sorry my question was not clear enough about this

Answer (score 1):

You could write the tool yourself, for example like this:

```
class UrlBuilder(object):
    def build(self, request):
        url = [ request['protocol'],
                '://',
                request['hostname'],
                ':',
                request['port'],
                request['page'],
                ]
        pars = request['parameters']
        if len(pars):
            url.append('?')
        parstr = []
        for key,val in pars.iteritems():
            val = str(val)
            val = val.replace(' ', '%20')
            parstr.append( '{key}={val}'.format(key=key, val=val) )
        url.append( '&'.join(parstr) ) 
        return ''.join(url)

request = {
  'protocol': "http",
  'hostname': "www.example.com",
  'port': "80",
  'page': "/foo/bar/example.php",
  'parameters': {
    'foo': "spaced parameter",
    'quuz': 42
  }
}

urlbuilder = UrlBuilder()
url = urlbuilder.build(request)
print url
```

Output:

```
http://www.example.com:80/foo/bar/example.php?foo=spaced%20parameter&quuz=42
```

Of course, this piece of code can be made more secure. For example, for now, spaced parameters with more than one space are not handled properly. Also, you might want to protect against a missing parameters key in the request input.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Actually, I was looking for something already deployed as lib, in order to not re-invent the wheel